# Show that the vector a+b is perpendicular to the line $AB$.

Tags: calculus, vectors

The position vectors of points $A$ and $B$ relative to the origin $O$ are **a** and **b** respectively and |**a**|=|**b**| .

How does one show that the vector **a**+**b** is perpendicular to the line $AB$?

I know that **a**$\cdot$**b** $=0$ when vector **a** and **b** are perpendicular, but how do I use this information to solve the above question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  direction of the line $AB$ can be represented by the vector $\mathbf b - \mathbf a$. (Thanks @amd!)

Now, $(\mathbf b - \mathbf a)\cdot(\mathbf a+\mathbf b) = -|\mathbf a|^2 + |\mathbf b|^2 = 0$ ( as $|\mathbf a| = |\mathbf b|$)

Comment: Fine point: the _direction_ of the line can be represented by $\mathbf b-\mathbf a$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the points $A$ and $B$ are distinct.We'll use parentheses for for points and brackets for vectors. Write $$A=(x_*,y_*),B(x_{**},y_{**}).$$
Then $$a=[x_*,y_*],b=[x_{**},y_{**}]$$ $$|a|=\sqrt(x_*^2+y_*^2),|b|=\sqrt(x_{**}^2+y_{**}^2)$$ 
$$\text {Since }|a|=|b|,\sqrt(x_*^2+y_*^2)=\sqrt(x_{**}^2+y_{**}^2) $$
$$\text{and thus }x_*^2+y_*^2=x_{**}^2+y_{**}^2$$
 $$\text{and so }x_{**}^2-x_*^2+y_{**}^2-y_*^2=0.$$ The vector $a+b$ is $[x_*+x_{**},y_*+y_{**}]$. A vector in the direction of the line $AB$ is $\mathbf v=[x_{**}-x_*,y_{**}-y_*]$. Showing that a vector is perpendicular to the line $AB$ is the same as showing that that vector is perpendicular to the vector $\mathbf v.$ Showing that two vectors are perpendicular is equivalent to showing that their dot product is 0.
$$\mathbf v \bullet (a+b)=[x_{**}-x_*,y_{**}-y_*]\bullet [x_*+x_{**},y_*+y_{**}]$$ $$=x_{**}^2-x_*^2+y_{**}^2-y_*^2=0,$$
$$Q.E.D..$$